# -fsanitize=address doesn't work on QtCreator (mac10.13)

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I used -fsanitize=address in the Qtcreator of Mac10.13, but the program did not print any detection information. Is it because my clang has a problem?

leak.cpp

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    int * ptr = new int();
    std::cout << "test leak memory check" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

build command:

```
clang++ leak.cpp -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -o leak.out
```

terminal output:

```
test leak memory check
```

Clang version

```
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

QtVerstion:5.11.1

Comment: [It's supposed to work as you have written it](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dffbb445f077c5a4). Check the Compile Output tab to see if that is really the command that Qt Creator used (sometimes it fails to update the underlying makefile and you have to manually click Run Cmake or Run Qmake).

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong sanitizer. When you compile with

```
clang++ -fsanitize=leak -fno-omit-frame-pointer -o leak.out
```

and execute the binary (tested on MacOS 10.13, too, with clang from trunk), you get

> ```
>  ==51079==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
>
> Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
> #0 0x10fa8fb65 in wrap__Znwm lsan_interceptors.cc:288
> #1 0x10fa7e1e8 in main (a.out:x86_64+0x1000011e8)
> #2 0x7fff5f490014 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1014)
> ```

Comment: That's clang built from trunk, so not a stable release.